# wildcard / dynamic div id not getting value with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a very basic need here and I can't figure out why it does not work.

For testing purpose I have 100 div's with id's of d_fav100, d_fav101, etc ...

And it just looks like a bunch of these

```
<div id='d_fav100'>This is DIV 100</div>
.
.
.
```

My jquery catch to grab the divs looks like this ...

```
   $("[id^='d_fav']").click( function() {
      var fav = $(this).val();
      alert(fav);
   });
```

However, I cannot get the value in the div assigned to the variable fav. The alert is always blank.

What am I missing?

Thanks for looking!

JT

Comment: Do not repeat id .Use class instead

Answer (score 1):

For a div, you should use the `.text()` method:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWBKay)

```
$("[id^='d_fav']").click( function() {
   var fav = $(this).text();
   alert(fav);
});
```

`.val()` will get the value for inputs/textareas.

Jquery's [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Did you see the codepen? Its working. You need to provide more context to get an answer that will work for your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to delegate the event. Also `div` does not have any `value` attribute. If you want to get the text use jquery `text` method

```
$('body').on('click' ,"div[id^='d_fav']",function(e){
 console.log($(this).text().trim())
})
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/qc5g3n61/4/)

Comment: *"It seems you need to delegate the event."* - That might be more efficient, but clearly the OP doesn't *need* to because their click handler is getting called as is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - you do not want the actual text of the div, but the value (number) of the div - ie: the 100 portion - which is the same in the id of the div.

Use a class and get the id from the div on the click event - remove the d_fav portion using substr(5) - and the remainder is the number you are after.

if it is the text you are after - then you can use the same code but use the .text() method as already described.

```js
$(".d_fav").click( function() {
      var fav = $(this).attr('id').substr(5);
      alert(fav);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d_fav" id='d_fav100'>This is DIV 100</div>
<div class="d_fav" id='d_fav101'>This is DIV 101</div>
<div class="d_fav" id='d_fav102'>This is DIV 102</div>
```